# how to avoid unnecessary check of reducer switch case

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I got two reducres that each one will handle a slice of state

my problem that those two contains huge switch case, or i found that redux is calling all reducers so each huge switch case gone be called ( because i'm using combineReudercs )

does it possible to target a specific reducer from the dispatch to avoid uncessary check of switch case ?

Comment: DO you have a concrete example? Anyways I think it is not possible

Comment: imagine any sample when u register two reducers that handle many actions

Comment: This is just how redux works - it will call all reducers that have been configured when creating your redux store, checking to see if the dispatched action matches any of the cases. In reality, as long as you're not doing anything crazy outside of your switch statements or something, performance shouldn't be particularly impacted :).

Comment: infact i'm thinking of replaceReducer also rootReducer that will delegate

Comment: but i wanna be sure that im in the right path

Comment: Do you have performance issues or you pre-optimizing?

Comment: pre before manager cry

Comment: Let him read this: https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/, and like @KierenHughes said, its really how redux work, it must traversal all action types.

Comment: thanks i gone check it

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I wouldn't use switch case hell. If you have a heavy page like you mentioned, you might had to handle lots of redux actions and it will be difficult to find any action in this switch case. For these scenarios, I'm using `key: value` format and also I recommend to all developers who are using redux. End of the day,your code will be readable and easy to manage. And I hope I understand your question well.

```js
  import { getProductsHandler, setProductsHandler } from './products.handlers'

  const initialState = {}

  // You can create another file for handlers 
  // In this case `getProductsHandler` and `setProductsHandler`
  export const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
    [GET_PRODUCTS]: getProductsHandler, 
    [SET_PRODUCTS]: setProductsHandler
  }

  const productReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const handler = ACTION_HANDLERS[action.type]
    return handler ? handler(state, action) : state
  }
```